# How to check "to number" is valid for Twillio SMS API?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am using `Twillio API` to send SMS to my website users. But there's one issue, I want to check first, if that number is valid or not? Is there any API in `Twillio` which is used to check validity of 'to' numbers?

Comment: can u post you code?

Comment: Code is working fine.If number is proper then it will send SMS but the thing is check first it is proper or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We actually do have an API that you can use to check the validity of a phone number. Check out the [Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) and its [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/lookups). At the basic level it checks to see if a number looks like a valid phone number and gives you the correct national formatting for it. You can also make a request to find out carrier details about the number to see if it is likely to receive SMS messages.

The link that @dhi_m provided is a good resource to find out what Twilio does with a number when sending it a message. Ultimately, the best way to see if you can send a message to a number is to try to send a message. Then you should build in ways to respond if the message is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [link](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-check-to-see-if-phone-numbers-can-receive-sms), Twilio’s API has basic validation to check whether this number is valid or not.

Comment: twilio link is broken